# What is the general recipe for Kafka Connect sinks exactly-once semantics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I read Kafka has added a lot to support exactly-once semantics. Things like idempotent producers, transactional producers, read committed consumers, and Kafka Streams exactly-once config. From my understanding though, this does not apply to Kafka Connect sinks? Would the general idea be then that the sink has to store the offset itself?

Comment: It depends on the sink... For example https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once

Comment: @cricket_007 I enjoyed that article. It makes sense that if it fails to save to the sink => retry from the last offset to make sure data is not missed; if it fails to commit back to Kafka after => retry from the last offset but make sure data is not duplicated in the sink by overwriting it by key, then the special case of S3 allowing multi-part uploads also prevents partial data. It seems like Kafka/Kafka Connect do most of the hard work, so when are some examples of cases where the sink must also store the offset itself?

Comment: HDFS sink stores the offsets as part of the file name and will resume from there. JDBC sink might work similarly